# Unable to Login with SYS user after importing dump in oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a general purpose database in oracle 11G server. Then I imported a dump    (using impdp and FULL= Y )that I received from customer using SYS with errors (ORA-31684 ,ORA-01917).Once the import is complete, I had to run some sqls with SYS login. This time when I try to login(I accidentally closed the SQL Plus window so I had to login again) using SYS it says Error:ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied. And when I connect like this.. CONN / as sysdba it says ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

If the SYS password is incorrect I think I should not be able to import the dump.

Its been more than a day and I'm still clueless. Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't really be performing an impdp as the SYS user, you should create another user with the privs to do it, or failing that use the SYSTEM user

Comment: OS is Windows 7 professional SP1

Comment: @davegreen100  Is it ? I'm unaware of it. Do you think this might be the cause?

Comment: probably not the cause of your problem, it's just an oracle recommendation. I would be surprised if anything in the import would have the password for the SYS user. Are you are able to sign in as any other user to the database? if so check if the SYS user account is locked

Comment: @davegreen I'm able to login with schema owner. I tried unlocking the sys user with schema owner and then I altered the sys user password successfully.I'm now able to connect using SYS. Your comment definitely gave me some hint to fix this.Thanks.